# Implementing Eraser functionality for drawing app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, drawing

I was following this great tutorial at ray wenderlich's site about creating a simple drawing app with UIKit.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit

the tutorial is great and everything is working. the problem that I have is that when it came to creating the eraser functionality the solution proposed by ray was to use the brush with the same color that the background has. To me this doesn't seem like a great solution. what if the background is not a solid color like a gradient or any image like in so many coloring book apps.

So basically the question is: is there a way to remove color (convert all pixels in that area to transparent maybe) from a UIImageView at a given location?

Any help or pointers would greatly be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using clearColor?

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629409/how-to-draw-a-transparent-stroke-or-anyway-clear-part-of-an-image-on-the-iphon 
but dont know how to implement this... any help???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue in my app after the long search i found the simple solution for this issue.

i just used touches methods of the `UIViewController`

The below is the my approach,

**Code:-**

```
   #pragma mark touches stuff...



 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];
    }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        currentTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];

        CGFloat brushSize;
        if (isEraser) 
        {
            brushSize=eraser;
        }
        else
        {
            brushSize=mark;
        }
        CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.editedImageView.frame.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.editedImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize);
        if (isEraser) {

            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.im].CGColor);
        }  
        else
        {
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear); 
        }
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        self.editedImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        lastTouch = [touch locationInView:self.editedImageView];
    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {

    }
```

**The Inputs:**

```
self.editedImageView.image = "Your Custom image";

self.im    =   "Your Custom image";
```

**The simple solution of your problem will be :-**

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:self.im].CGColor);
```

**Note:**

This not unerase it again drawing the image over

**Update:-**

```
 self.im    =   "Your Custom image";
```

this will be like this....

```
-(void)eraserConfigure
{
    UIImageView *resizeImage=[[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:editedImage]autorelease];
    /*UIImage */self.im=[UIImage imageFromView:resizeImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(self.editedImageView.frame.size.width, self.editedImageView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: Note: this not erasing but redrawing the again with the same for your case if your background is white or some other color then use that color or image mean use the above code

Comment: awesome... had to fight with the code a bit .. mine was bit too messed up but finally got it to work.. thanks

Comment: @UmerHassam Thanks and facing any issue let me know

Answer (score 1):

Use the brush but for the color use:

```
[UIColor clearColor]
```

Comment: Trying using CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor instead. CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor)

Answer (score 1):

I could solve the issue using below code:

```
CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeClear);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939096/erasing-after-drawing-with-cgcontext/9043950#9043950)